# Inno Setup does not seem to write to the registry on a 64-bit machine

Tags: windows, registry, installation, inno-setup

I have a very simple Inno Setup script containing this `[Registry]` section:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE; Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist; ValueType: string; ValueName: ABC; ValueData: abc
```

However, when I check the `HKLM\SOFTWARE` subkey, there is no value added.

I tried different subkeys under the `HKLM\SOFTWARE` and Pascal scripting, but Inno Setup simply refuses to create a new subkey or value.

I am running a 64bit Windows 7, the UAC is turned off.

Comment: Have you explicitly specified the `PrivilegesRequired` directive value ? I'm asking because if you changed it to something different from `admin` value, InonSetup doesn't run the setup elevated, thus it might not have rights to write to the `HKLM` root. Could you include this information into your question ?

Comment: @TLama The problem was in registry virtualization of 32 bit applications. I have added an answer.

Comment: @TLama Sorry I forgot to answer you. As I wrote in the question: "the UAC is turned off", hence the problem was not in missing admin privileges.

Comment: No problem. But it's not about *"UAC is turned off"*, when you'd run the setup with `PrivilegesRequired` below `admin`, the setup wouldn't even run with admin elevation (no matter UAC is on or off), thus you wouldn't have those rights at all. That's why that response was mandatory...

Answer (score 20):

Finally solved it.

Inno Setup was running as 32bit on a 64bit machine, hence HKLM correspond to HKLM\Wow6432Node.

I need to add check for IsWin64 and use HKLM64 in that case. I think the syntax should be:

`Root: HKLM64; ... <Subkey, Flags, etc.> ... Check: IsWin64`

Comment: Just make sure you don't actually write to SOFTWARE itself.  Use a Company\AppName subkey.

Comment: Of course, I just wanted to make the example simple so that no one will discuss that the subkey possibly does not exist etc.

Comment: Libor, Can you show me how you did that? Because when I add IsWin64 in the [Registry] field it gives me an error saying Root element missing.

Comment: @Govs I think the syntax should be: `Root: HKLM64; ... <Subkey, Flags, etc.> ... Check: IsWin64`. However, I am now using just the constant `HKLM` (or `HKCU`) because it always points to the correct location. Otherwise you have to use both `IsWin64` check and `HKLM32` or `HKLM64` which is unnecessary in most cases.